# How should I save large strings (or other data types) to a file in a php webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, file, post, save

I have a practice webpage form that has users fill out their name and a bio.  I want to save the bio to a file on the server (aka in my localhost directory) and just store the link to the file in the database to save database memory and transaction time.

Should I just have the user submit all of the data, posting it to another php and then extract the bio and save it?  Or is there a way I can use javascript to first save the bio to a file, then pass the link to that file back to the php page which then gets submitted through post and sent to the database?

Basically I know how to do it in both PHP and javascript, but I'm not sure how to combine the two.  My ***ideal situation*** would be that the user fills out their name and bio, hits enter (aka clicks submit), the bio gets saved to a file and the link to that file gets added to $_POST (along with the name) which then obviously posts the info to the `action="blahblah.php"` page.

What is the best way to achieve this

Comment: If you think a typed biography requires such careful optimisations, you'd better not implement profile pictures... :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario as I said this is just a practice site, I have no intention of making this live or ever allowing another human soul to see the monstrosity that is the design of this site. I just want to learn the process so that down the line, if say I want users on another site to be able to save their 50 page long documents or whatever I'll know how to do it.

Comment: store in database but setup some query caching

Comment: Store the data in a database. Its pre-optimized for data access where a file system is not. You would never do it the way you suggest in real life so why do it that way for a test.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've heard this is the way to store images if you plan on having a lot of them.  If that is true, I would like to learn how to do it this way before I move on to images.